# Casting string to bytes while parsing XML to Objects ('str' does not support the buffer interface)

Tags: python, casting, xml-parsing

I encountered a problem while using function parseString

```
xml.sax.parseString(src, builder)
```

TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

I trying change this calling to:

```
xml.sax.parseString(bytes(src,'utf-8'), builder)
```

but still not working

Python 3.2

Comment: What version of Python? Did you try `src.encode('utf-8')`?

Comment: Yes, still nothing. Python 3.2

Comment: And with the utf-8 bytes, are you getting the same error?

Comment: Yes. I found similiar problem here, but there is also no clearly solution:
http://mail.python.org/pipermail/docs/2010-November/002269.html